# Cannot disable F14 and F15 keyboard shortcuts controlling the brightness

Tags: keyboard, settings

I read this question/answer: [Disable F14/F15 for Brightness Control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287614/disable-f14-f15-for-brightness-control)

I have a different problem, I can see these options, I can check and uncheck them:

[image]

But even when the options are unchecked, <kbd>F14</kbd> and <kbd>F15</kbd> still control the brightness. What's wrong?

I have the [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay) tool, but I can't see additional keyboard shortcuts.

I already have the standard <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> keys controlling the brightness, so <kbd>F14</kbd> and <kbd>F15</kbd> are really useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. There was really an option to deactivate in the BetterDisplay tool settings:

[image]